# Getting input from file troubles C++

Tags: c++, file, input, getline, istream

I've been trying to read some information in from a .txt file in C++ but it's not all working like I expect. Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char words[255];
    int value = 0;

    ifstream input_stream("test.txt");

    input_stream >> value;
    input_stream.getline(words, 256);

    cout << value << endl;
    cout << words << endl;
}
```

And test.txt contains:

```
1234
WordOne WordTwo
```

What I expect is for the code to print the two lines contained in the text file, but instead I just get:

```
 1234
```

I've been reading about getline and istream but can't seem to find any solutions so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to print the output of another getline, and see what you find.  This has to do with newline characters being consumed or not.

Comment: I guess that's because getline founds the new-line character after the first string (1234) and stops.

Answer (score 3):

The newline character remains in the input stream after the read of the integer:

```
// Always check result to ensure variables correctly assigned a value.
if (input_stream >> value)
{
}
```

Then, the call to `getline()` reads the newline character and stops, producing an empty string. To correct, consume the newline character before calling `getline()` (options include using `getline()` or [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)).

Note there is a version [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that accepts a `std::string` as its argument to avoid using a fixed sized array of `char`, which is used incorrectly in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

ifstream's getline method gathers input until one of two options is hit.  Either a terminating character or the size passed in is reached.  In your case, the newline terminator is encountered before the size is reached.

Use another getline to retrieve the second line of text.

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat corrected version of your original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char words[256];                  // was 255
    int value = 0;

    ifstream input_stream("test.txt");

    input_stream >> value;
    input_stream.ignore();            // skip '\n'
    input_stream.getline(words, 256);

    cout << value << endl;
    cout << words << endl;
}
```

Also, I would advise you to use a `string` instead of a `char[]` and use [the other `getline` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is that the first newline after `1234` is not consumed by `input_stream>>(int)`; so the next getline only reads to the end of that file.

This is a very constructed scenario, commonly found in schoolwork. The more common scenario when reading a textfile is to consider the entire file as linebased text.

In this case the more convenient

```
string line;
while( std::getline( input_stream, line ) ){

}
```

is appropriate, and way less error prone.

The textfile would commonly have a predefined format. Perhaps `name = value` lines, and are parsed as such *after* the line is read from the file.